# sending kafka mertics via Opentelemetry

Tags: apache-kafka, open-telemetry

I have a spring boot application whoch produces data and consumes data from Kafka.
I am trying to send Kafka metrics to opentelemetry collector, so that it can be visualised via Grafana.

Does spring boot support sending kafka metrics?

Answer (score 0):

You need `spring-kafka` or `kafka-clients` to get Kafka metrics, not just Boot.

Outside of using `opentelemetry-javaagent.jar`, you can use Spring Actuator to expose Kafka client metrics (and more) to a Prometheus scape target, which can then be visualized in Grafana.